# how to enable-cors in GKE with ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to enable cors with ingress without success using the following annotation:

```
 kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
```

Comment: Where are you putting these things?

Comment: kubernetes.yaml

Comment: had the same problem, did some googling and found that the gce ingress controller doesnt support enable-cors: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/docs/annotations.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct annotation is `ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"`

Comment: Yes, the nginx controller must be used instead of gce.

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplement to the approved answer for people using Kubernetes on GCP.

If people having an existing ingress running with class `gce`, they need to switch over to `nginx` first.

Then you should follow the installation steps at [NGINX Ingress Controller - Installation Guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy).

But please note, if you are using Kubernetes 1.8+, you have RBAC enabled by default. This might give you an error while running the first RBAC installation line. The error is like: "*Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "STDIN": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress-clusterrole" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges*".

While having this configuration step failed, the nginx ingress controller won't run, it will crash over and over again complaining about RBAC.

When I did a search on the net myself, I found a post related to this error and it helped me to get a running nginx ingress controller.

Please read the [post by user dafstone at March 5 2018](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1663#issuecomment-370448456).

It adds your GCP account as a cluster admin which allows you to install the required RBAC rules as explained in the installation guide at first.

Good luck!