# How to enable CORS with ingress without using nginx?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to setup RESTful API application with Kubernetes.  I have a barebones setup with a cluster, static IP address, app deployed with exposed service of type NodePort, and an ingress configured with a managed certificate for SSL.  I need to enable CORS and I am not yet using nginx.  Is it possible, or do I need to install nginx instead of the default gce class?

Here is my ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: artsdata-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "artsdasta-static-ip"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: artsdata-certificate
    ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: artsdata-kg
    servicePort: 80
```

To check I am using curl as follows:

```
curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: http://localhost" --head http://db.artsdata.ca
```

I am expecting the response to include Access-Control-Allow-*

Answer (score 2):

Currently [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) mechanism is not supported in GCP L7 load balancer, therefore [ingress-gce](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) ingress controller does contain appropriate [annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/pkg/annotations/ingress.go) to accomplish this functionality, find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190429/how-to-enable-cors-in-gke-with-ingress) related Stack thread.

If you consider replacing native GCP Ingress class by [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) in order to enable [Cross-origin](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors) requests then you might have to include at least two annotations in the origin Ingress resource definition:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
```

I've found a great [guideline](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) through GCP community tutorials that explains Nginx Ingress Controller implementation procedure in GKE.

There are also the other L7 proxy frameworks available on the market that can leverage CORS requests like [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/headers/), [Skipper](https://github.com/zalando/skipper/blob/master/docs/kubernetes/ingress-controller.md), etc.