# CORS issues when running a dockerised FastAPI application

Tags: https, cors, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a [`fastapi`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) application running and working just fine. I want to use my fastapi application to serve as backend for my react frontend deployed on firebase hosting (https). Running locally (http fastpi and react) I got it working by enabling CORS in FastAPI

```py
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

But when I deployed I realized that I couldn't serve fastapi as HTTP since my frontend is on HTTPS. I went ahead and created a kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud and ingressed my dockerised fastapi application (exposed as HTTPS). That works when I curl to my HTTPS fastapi endpoint but I'm getting CORS issues again in my react app and this time I don't know how to solve it. How come the above doesn't apply any longer?

The CORS error is

> Access to fetch at 'https://my-api-domain' from origin 'https://my-frontend-domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

### EDIT

I just did some further investigation and I can conclude that if I run my container locally with `docker run` then `access-control-allow-origin` is properly returned in the header. But when deployed on GKE then there are no `access-control-allow-origin`.

### UPDATE

I've tried installing nginx ingress instead of GKE ingress but that complicates things regardin global static IP and google managed certificate. I need a solution that gives me

1. Global static IP (ok with GKE ingress)
2. Google Managed Certificate (ok with GKE ingress)
3. CORS enabled (ok with nginx ingress)

So I'm stuck atm!

### LATEST UPDATE

I'm using Nginx Ingress Controller with `cert-manager` and it works like a charm. Bonus info: running everything with skaffold and kustomize as well - so many great tools

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I’ve supplied the original post with the error

Comment: Have you checked this thread? [How to enable CORS in GKE ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190429/how-to-enable-cors-in-gke-with-ingress)

Comment: Yes that uses nginx ingress instead. And I can’t use Google Managed Certificates with nginx ingress which is a requirement

Comment: Is there any particular reason that the google managed certificate is a requirement? Couldn't this be done for example with `cert-manager` inside of gke cluster? Please take a look here: [Github.com: How to assign a static-ip to an Ingress on through the Nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/static-ip). If it came to conclusion that `cert-manager` could be used, the nginx ingress should satisfy all the requirements.

Comment: @mr.bjerre Does combination `Nginx Ingress Controller` with `Cert-Manager` resolved your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this `Community Wiki` for better visibility as solution was mention in `comment section`.

If you would like to use `CORS` on `Google Cloud Platform`, you have to use `Nginx Ingress` and specific `GCP` annotation. More details about this you can find in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190429/how-to-enable-cors-in-gke-with-ingress)

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
```

**Solution**

Solution for this issue was to use [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) and [Cert-Manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) with proper annotations.

Also OP confirmed it's working.

> I'm using `Nginx Ingress Controller` with `cert-manager` and it works like a charm. Bonus info: running everything with `skaffold` and `kustomize` as well - so many great tools

Answer (score 4):

Adding the middleware after the default endpoint solved the issue for me.

```
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")

def home():
return {"message":"Health Check Passed!"}

app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware,
allow_origins=["*"],
allow_credentials=True,
allow_methods=["*"],
allow_headers=["*"],)
```

Comment: howw??? its works like a charm ! but how can you please explain ?

Comment: Unbelievable, it worked. can you explain. I've been on this for hours.

Comment: If this works, then it's a really strange bug in FastAPI...

Comment: would have been too nice, didn't work for me