# CORS block request from ReacJS frontend to python FastAPI application

Tags: python, reactjs, docker, cors, fastapi

I use FastAPI to deploy an API on local server, using docker, something like this: http://192.168.1.33:8090/myAPI
I already set allow CORS like this:

```py
app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "*",
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Calling from inside the network, it works fine.

When I map domain from outside to my API: https://example.com/myAPI
then the CORS error happens.
`Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/myAPI' from origin 'https://example2.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I also tried to change `origins` in above code to `origins = ["https://example2.com"]` but it not work.

I know some people facing a similar question here: [CORS issues when running a dockerised FastAPI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680870/cors-issues-when-running-a-dockerised-fastapi-application) but he runs his docker in k8s.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: iirc if you end up getting a 404 or 500 either of those skip your cors

Comment: I have tried send request using postman and it works fine with code 200 and the cors issue is happen on browser

Answer (score 2):

I just added `expose_headers=["*"]` in CORSMiddleware and it worked fine for me:

```py
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["*"])
```

Also I don't recommend using "*" in origins. I solved tons of errors just by changing it.

Comment: didn't work for me. It only doesn't work on virtual machine though but it does on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["*"])
```

working for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).